# Using a genetic algorithm to guess an image

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to write a genetic algorithm which will take in a given image and then produce that image. I have already achieved this for 28x28 white and black images, but I am struggling to work out how to do it for larger RGB images.

I thought I would start by generating the individuals in the population, so I randomly generated a list of size x*y where x and y are the dimensions of the input image, and each item within the list is in the format (r, g, b). Like this

```
random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(pixel_amount, 3))
generated_colours = [tuple(colour) for colour in random_numbers.tolist()]
```

In order to evaluate fitness, I went through each pixel in the image I want to produce, and the individual in the population and then I checked to see how many of the pixels were the correct colour in the correct place. However, this is clearly not a good approach as there are 256^3 combinations for each colour. As such, I thought it might be a better idea to evaluate it based on how many of the individual r, g and b values are correct. Therefore, an image of 28x28 pixels would have a maximum fitness of 28*28*3 = 2352 (in this case this is good, whereas a low fitness is usually ideal so you can invert it). Although, I thought perhaps it could be a better idea to instead look at exactly how far away the individual r, g and b values in each individual in the population are from the r, g and b values in the image we want, in a similar fashion to a cost function of a neural network. However, I'm not sure exactly how I would implement this. Perhaps

```
fitness = 0
for i in range(pixel_amount):
    given_image_rgb = given_image_pixels[i]
    individual_rgb = individual_pixels[i]
    for j in range(3):
        fitness += (individual_rgb[j] - given_image_rgb[j])**2
```

So if the fitness remains at zero, it is because the image is exactly correct. Whereas, if it is higher than it is further from what we want. Although, I think this would give very large numbers as for only a 28x28 image the worst possible fitness is 28*28*3*255^3 = 152938800.

So, assuming I can get the fittest individuals in the population, I was going to remove the worst half of the individuals. Then, I would breed the fittest individuals to create the next generation. I was thinking of doing this by randomly selecting two individuals from the remaining half. Then, I randomly pick half the pixel coordinates and I take those pixels from parent1, and the other half of the pixels from parent2 to make child1. Then, I take the inverse in order to form child2. This would continue until the initial population size has been restored. However, I think that this crossover needs to not just combine pixels, but also combine (r, g, b) values of the pixels. Perhaps calculate an average across the two and always round down? Here is the current approach:

```
first_child = [None for _ in range(pixel_amount)]
second_child = [None for _ in range(pixel_amount)]
first_parent = first_parent[1]
second_parent = second_parent[1]
for i in range(pixel_amount):
    if i in random_pixels:
        first_child[i] = first_parent[i]
        second_child[i] = second_parent[i]
    else:
        first_child[i] = second_parent[i]
        second_child[i] = first_parent[i]
return first_child, second_child
```

After that, I would mutate the individuals which would involve randomly changing a certain % of the pixels in each individual. Say 0.25% of each image would get set to a random (r, g, b) value.

```
for individual in population:
    mutated_pixels = random.sample(range(pixel_amount - 1), int(pixel_amount * mutation_rate))
    for pixel in mutated_pixels:
        individual[pixel] = tuple(np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=3))
```

In terms of a stopping condition, I was going to calculate what percentage of the pixels, or what percentage of the rgb values are correct, and then have it stop once it has reached a certain % correct - say 70%.

I'm sorry for a rather long post, but I would really appreciate some advice on how I can get this working for larger colour images. I understand that it may be practically impossible using this approach, and so I have begun to look into using a set of translucent polygons instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use **Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)** in your search space? Select a random sampling with a given restriction to decrease the search space. You keep crossover at around *60%* and mutation at *1%* and select random images with a given restriction, let's say average of pixels inside a given threshold related to the image you want to reconstruct. Although the selection process is sub-optimal, you can use the roulette wheel based on **Expectation Maximization** algorithm as a way to overcome this heuristic approach, as well as the threshold in the choice of fittest individuals.

Comment: I don't know what an MCMC is, but are you saying that for my initial population I should only generate [ixels which have rgb values close to the correct rgb values? Is that not considered cheating?

Comment: Also what does 60% crossover mean in practice? And 1% mutation?

Comment: And can you explain what you mean by using a roulette wheel based on EM?

Comment: How does EM apply if I don't have any observed available data?

Comment: RGB values are generated randomly, the stochastic process. 60% crossover mean that you will exchange genetic material between parents to create a sample, 1% mutation will slightly increase variance in data and the EM algorithm will select only the most probable samples given the inputs of previous round, which is known. This is doable.

Comment: I understand what crossover is, but you haven't explained what you mean by 60% crossover in practice. It can mean a LOT of different things.